# $key=$_REQUEST['key'] doesnt work

Tags: php, mysql, request, key

```
if (isset($_POST['cancel'])) {
    print("<script>location.href = 'task_led.php'</script>");
}
else if (isset($_POST['assign'])) {
    $atask = $_POST['task'];
    $table_task = $_POST['hid_task'];
    $key = $_REQUEST['key'];

    include 'sql.php';

    $SQL = " ALTER TABLE $table_task ADD $atask VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL";
    mysql_query($SQL);

    $SQL = "UPDATE info SET individ_task = '$atask' WHERE username = '$key'";
    mysql_query($SQL);


    $SQL = "INSERT INTO $table_task (`username`, $atask) VALUES ('$key',     'pending')";
    mysql_query($SQL);

    $SQL = "UPDATE info SET task_status_indi = 'pending' WHERE username = '$key'";
    mysql_query($SQL);

    mysql_close($db_handle);
    print("<script>location.href = 'task_led.php'</script>");
}
else{   

    $namekey = $_REQUEST['key'];
    $user = $_SESSION['username'];
    include 'sql.php';

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM info WHERE username = '$user'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $grp = $db_field['groups'];//telephone_tech
        $tsk = $db_field['group_task'];//resolve_telephone
    }

    print("<div style='top:167; left:380; position:absolute; z-index:1;'>");
    print("<table border = '0' width = '370' bgcolor = 'white'>");
    print("<tr><td>$tsk</td></tr>");
    print("</table>");
    print("</div>");

    $SQL = "SELECT * FROM task_list WHERE taskname = '$tsk'";
    $result = mysql_query($SQL);
    while ($db_field = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        $dsc = $db_field['ds'];
    }

    print("<div style='top:200; left:250; position:absolute; z-index:1;'>");
    print("<font face='Broadway' size = '4'>Description:</font>");
    print("</div>");

    print("<div style='top:197; left:380; position:absolute; z-index:1;'>");
    print("<table border = '0' width = '370' bgcolor = 'white'>");
    print("<tr><td>$dsc</td></tr>");
    print("</table>");
    print("</div>");

    print("<div style='top:270; left:350; position:absolute; z-index:1;'>");
    print("<form name='add_form' method='post' action='add_task_led.php'>");
    print("<table border = '0' >");
    print("<tr><td><b>Name:</b></td>");
    print("<td><input name = 'uname' type = 'text' readonly = 'true' value = $namekey></td>");
    print("</tr>");
    print("<tr><td><b>Task:</b></td>");
    print("<td><input name = 'task' type = 'text' value = ''></td>");
    print("<input name = 'hid_task' type = 'hidden' value = $tsk>");
    print("</tr>"); 
    print("<tr>");
    print("<td align = 'right'><input name = 'reset' type = 'reset' value = 'reset'></td>");
    print("<td><input name = 'cancel' type = 'submit' value = 'cancel'>");
    print("<input name = 'assign' type = 'submit' value = 'ASSIGN'></td>");
    print("</tr>");
    print("</table>");
    print("</form>");
    print("</div>");
    mysql_close($db_handle);
}
```

I need help with this one it is supposed to get the key from URL like `nbproject/add_task_led.php?key=Marija` to put it in $key variable and it doesn't seem to work. When I put the name directly in this example Marija instead of `$key` it changes the DB. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How doesn't it work? Do you get an error? What does it say? What have you done to debug this? Have you tried `$key = $_GET['key'];`?

Comment: it is supposed to assign certain task to a member and switch to task_led.php script when it is assigned. However when i click assign it does nothing (adds a task in the DB but doesnt assign the name)

Comment: did you pass the `key` value!!

Comment: What does $key contain right after the assignment?

Comment: i'm new to php and mysql so i dont know what you mean how do i pass key

Comment: I assume Krish means whether you actually have ?key=Marija in your call...

Comment: $key value should contain the key from URL in this case Marija. Am i missing something?

Comment: This might not be it, but check the line "INSERT INTO $table_task (`username`, .... It has the wrong kind of quotes around 'username'. That could be messing up the INSERT statement.

Comment: `action='add_task_led.php?key=Marija'` add this in your form tag or pass the key value in hidden method `<input type="hidden" name="key" value="<?php echo $_GET['key'];?>">`. i.e when submiting the form you have not carried out the key value. that is the issue.

Comment: I know, but what does $key actually contain. Put a var_dump($key) right after the $key = $_REQUEST['key']; line.

Comment: No, the quotes as you call them (backticks) around `username` are OK. These are used for column names. @BrettFromLA - it's more like the 2nd value trying to be inserted that could be a fault `$atask`

Comment: use var_dump($_REQUEST['key']); what does that show?

Comment: Since you're using sessions `$user = $_SESSION['username'];` is `session_start();` inside and at the top of your page(s)? @user3251163 - If it isn't you need to have it.

Comment: If I'm reading the logic right, it looks as though a value is only inserted into the database if the URL doesn't contain a value for the parameter "cancel" and it does contain a value for the parameter "assign". In other words, the URL in your example wouldn't lead to an insert because it doesn't contain the parameter "assign".

Comment: The `assign` variable is coming from the submit button `<input name = 'assign' type = 'submit' value = 'ASSIGN'>` - That only checks if the submit button was clicked, and if so, to execute the code. @BrettFromLA - `if (isset($_POST['assign']))` - what I think it could be is the actual `href` link not being done properly and missing the actual parameter. Hard to tell without seeing full code and the OP seems to have gone to get another cup of coffee/Espresso/Latte.

Comment: You're welcome, and thanks. Now, it's my turn to get me another cup of coffee lol @BrettFromLA - Cheers

Comment: You see, the OP wrote ***"When i put the name directly in this example Marija instead of $key it changes the DB..."*** - so this tells me that the `href` is not done properly. We need to see the actual HTML in order to be 100% certain and to leave it out of the equation. @BrettFromLA - I also have my money on the potentially missing `session_start()`

Comment: However, [`Krish's comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21465375/key-requestkey-doesnt-work#comment32394965_21465375) also makes a lot of sense. @BrettFromLA - I think I'll give up on this question, since there is no further interaction on OP's part. Cheers, see you on the flip side.

Comment: If `$key` is `it's broken` you're going to have a bad day. Please read up on [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php) to avoid severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) like this. **NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in a query.

Comment: change $key = $_REQUEST['key']; by $key = $_POST['key'];...

Comment: Errrr... no. You'll never get a result for `add_task_led.php?key=Marija` using POST. @kraysak - Either `GET` or `REQUEST`

Comment: @Fred-ii-  why? the form use post method..

Comment: That's a completely different operation. You can use POST for variables being POSTed, and to query a DB using `GET/REQUEST` at the same time. @kraysak

Comment: i appreciate all the help but i still can't make this work :/

Comment: when i use $key=$_GET['key'];
      echo $key; in front of the if statement at the begining of the script it outputs the key but when i put it in the sql statements it doesnt change the DB :/

Comment: Then try `$key = $_GET['key'];` and/or `WHERE username = $key"` or `WHERE username = '".$key."'"` or `WHERE username = '".$_GET['key'].'"` @user3251163

Comment: Or try `WHERE username=" . $key";` along with my other comment about `$key = $_GET['key'];` instead of `$key = $_REQUEST['key'];` @user3251163

Comment: form method is post.so at the time of form submit the key is missing.

Answer (score 0):

### For testing purposes

Can you setup a **test table** with the following code that I concluded as being successful.

Be sure to change these variables to fit your own, or create them as shown:

```
$table_task = "table_task"; // table name
$atask = "a_task"; // column name
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $db); // db_name is your DB
```

**HTML/PHP/SQL** (form action is set to self)

```
<?php
if (!empty($_REQUEST['key'])) {
  $key = $_REQUEST['key'];
  echo "key: ". $key. "\n";

$db = mysql_connect("host","username", "password");

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db_name', $db);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ('Can\'t use it : ' . mysql_error());
}

$table_task = "table_task";
$atask = "a_task";

$SQL = "INSERT INTO $table_task (`username`, $atask) VALUES ('$key', 'pending')";
mysql_query($SQL,$db);

// Used for my own testing purposes that you can comment out
// $SQL = "UPDATE $table_task SET a_task = 'pending_test' WHERE username = '$key'";
// mysql_query($SQL,$db);

}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body>

<form action="" method="get">
User: <input type="text" name="key" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
</form>

</body>
</html>
```